# How can I identify which directories are on a different file system?

Tags: filesystems, command, btrfs

Imagine I am in a directory (e.g., `/mnt`) where some of the directories are mountpoints of another file system, and other directories are legitimate directories on the same filesystem. Can I issue a simple command to list the contents of the current directory in a way that allows me to distinguish those two kinds of directories?

One possibility would be `tree -L 1 -x`, which will only expand those folders which are on the same filesystem, but this does not work in case all of these folders are empty (i.e., empty file systems are mounted to the mountpoints, and the legitimate directories are empty directories).

(My real use case here is btrfs file systems, to be able to identify easily which directories are subvolumes and which are not.)

**Edit:** I got the suggestion from friends to use `df` to obtain the mountpoint of each file, so it is possible to list all folders on a different filesystem by running the following:

```
comm -1 -3 \
  <(df --output=target . | sort) \
  <(df --output=target * | sort | uniq) |
  xargs basename -a
```

The command runs `df` on all files to obtain their mountpoint, and removes the output of `df` in the current directory (which also removes the header), then retrieves the basename of each file. However, this is not especially elegant and is brittle (at least because of newlines, maybe because of things that I overlooked). Is there a better way?

Comment: Something in combination with `findmnt` might help you. Though, I haven't used in this way yet so I am not sure.

Comment: @phk: Thanks for the idea, but from a quick look at the manpage I did not get specific ideas

Comment: What output/outcome you expect is unclear to me. Do you want something like `find -xdev` or `du -ax` or `btrfs sub list`?

Comment: See also `find . -printf '%D %p\n'` to print the device number.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks! I guess indeed you can do a solution based on the device number. What I was looking for was a simple command for that (or maybe some way to add the information to the output of ls), but I guess this just doesn't exist. Thanks still!

Comment: I'm still not sure what kind of output you're expecting. See also `namei -x -- *` on Linux.

Comment: Or `find . -exec mountpoint -q {} \; -print`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: The output I was expecting was: all directories in the pwd, labeled differently depending on whether they are mountpoints or not. `mountpoint` seemed promising but apparently it does not consider btrfs subvolumes as mountpoints. However, I think `namei -x -- *` is a very nice solution (though I'd pipe it through `grep '^ '`), I'll accept it if you post it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `df` for this.

```
$ cd /usr

$ ls
X11R6       include     libexec     mdec        sbin        xobj
bin         lib         local       obj         share       xsrc
games       libdata     lost+found  ports       src

$ for d in *; do test -d "$d" && df -P "$d" | awk -v d="$d" 'FNR>1{print d,$NF}'; done 
X11R6 /usr
bin /usr
games /usr
include /usr
lib /usr
libdata /usr
libexec /usr
local /usr/local
lost+found /usr
mdec /usr
obj /usr
ports /usr/ports
sbin /usr
share /usr
src /usr
xobj /usr
xsrc /usr
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's the same idea than the `df`-based solution I just added as an edit to my question. It's not as elegant as I would have hoped, but oh well...

Answer (score 1):

With **stat** (could overflow ARG_MAX if * expands to something extremely huge):

```
stat -c '%D %n' */ | awk -v no=$(stat -c %D /) ' $1 != no { print $2 }'
```

With **find**:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%D\t%P\n'  |grep -v "^$(stat -c%d /)" |cut -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can use [`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) to list a unique identifier associated to each mounted filesystem:

```
stat -f -c %i somefile
```

So for example to list the mount points under the current directory (assuming no newlines in file names) you can run

```
stat -f -c '%i %n' * | grep -v "^$(stat -f -c %i .)"
```

In zsh, you can use the [`zsh/stat` module](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fstat-Module). Load it with `zmodload zsh/stat`, then

```
zstat +device *
```

To list mount points in the current directory:

```
zstat +device * | grep -v " $(zstat +device .)"
```

or

```
print -rl -- *(e\''[[ $(zstat +device $REPLY) == '$(zstat +device .)' ]]'\')
```

Note that the filesystem identifier is the same for different views of the same filesystem, for example if you mount the same network share at different 
locations, or with Linux bind mounts. However btrfs subvolumes do get their own identifier. [Parsing the output of `df`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296463) is more fiddly but does not have this limitation.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Just wanted to point out to other readers that `zmodload zsh/stat` will also replace `stat` by its zsh built-in definition, for which `-f` does not mean the same thing. You can avoid this by loading the module using `zmodload -F zsh/stat b:zstat`